# How to reformat a USB drive with "no file system"?

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive

I have a flash drive I got as some sort of promotion and just for the heck of it I tried to erase it and use it for my purposes. However there is nothing I could do to reformer, erase, zero out, etc this drive. Diskutil info says:

```
   Device Identifier:        disk2
   Device Node:              /dev/disk2
   Part of Whole:            disk2
   Device / Media Name:      SMI USB DISK Media
   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)
   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)
   File System:              None
   Content (IOContent):      FDisk_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               1.0 GB (1018167296 Bytes) (exactly 1988608 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          Yes
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

I am doing this on a Mac with OSX 10.9 and it shows up like a perfectly normal file system, folders, hidden files etc.

Is there anything I can do with this drive except throwing it away?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not good with OSX, but as with many UNIX systems, try `fdisk` command to partition and then `mkfs.[filesystem]` to create the filesystem

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> Read-Only Media:          Yes
> ```

OS says no.

Answer (score 0):

Some USB drives have a physical write protection switch. If it's in "Read Only" mode, the OS wouldn't be able to write.

Possible solution to your problem is to check if the USB drive has such a switch, and if it does - change it to "Write/Read" mode.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions:

1. in terminal, `cat /dev/zero > /dev/sd...` where `sd...` is pendrive's DRIVE designation (not partition path like e.g. `/dev/sd1`). You'd just clobber partition table and everything on it with zeros. That's how it works on Linux though, I have no idea what's the equivalent on OS X.
2. On Windows, I'd use Bootice utility which I dimly remember has the option of formatting it in HDD manner or removing or recreating partition table, etc.